# Weird error trying to connect to Kubernetes UI

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running on GKE, and connected to my cluster using the proxy command. when I visit `localhost:8001/ui`, I get this error.

`Error: 'ssh: rejected: connect failed (Connection refused)'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.56.40.3:9090/'`

Is there something wrong with some system service? How can I just bounce the ui deployment? I can't seem to find in the docs where this service is even defined.

Comment: what's the proxy command you're trying to use? I usually do `start kubectl proxy` then go to localhost:8080 and that works fine, if not we can dig a bit deeper, can you confirm?